# Как разбить данные из одного столбца и вставить их в два новых?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Нужно из столбца `Общие данные` (красный) вырезать гео-данные и вставить в два столбца - `Широта` и `Долгота` (синие).

```
import pandas
    
data = {'Имя': ['Москва, 1п.', 'Питер, 2п', 'Владик 3пп', 'Калининград'],
            'Координаты': ['53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708',
                           '53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708',
                           '53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292',
                           '53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292']}
    
    
data2 = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    
data2['Общие данные'] = data2['Имя'] + ', ' + data2['Координаты'].astype(str)
    
data2.sort_values(['Общие данные'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
    
data2.to_excel('test1.xlsx')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть принятые стандарты для импорта некоторых модулей. Например, `import pandas as pd`. Будет лучше, если вы будете из придерживаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data2[["Широта", "Долгота"]] = pandas.DataFrame(data2["Координаты"]
                                                .str.split(",",expand=True), index = data2.index)
```

результат:

```
           Имя                          Координаты                                     Общие данные            Широта            Долгота
2   Владик 3пп    53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292     Владик 3пп, 53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292    53.25932749912   83.6534465959292
3  Калининград    53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292    Калининград, 53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292    53.25932749912   83.6534465959292
0  Москва, 1п.  53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  Москва, 1п., 53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  53.2555095749943   83.6533059729708
1    Питер, 2п  53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708    Питер, 2п, 53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  53.2555095749943   83.6533059729708
```

**UPDATE**

после уточнений автора вопроса, что из колонки с общими данными нужно убрать все, кроме городов:

```
# сначала нужно заменить запятую, которая встречается в названии города:
data2['Общие данные'] = data2['Имя'].str.replace(",",";") + ', ' + data2['Координаты'].astype(str)

# а затем уже сделать наше преобразование, но уже для 3 колонок:
data2[["Общие данные", "Широта", "Долгота"]] = pd.DataFrame(data2["Общие данные"]
                                                .str.split(",", expand=True), index = data2.index)
```

результат:

```
           Имя                          Координаты Общие данные             Широта            Долгота
2   Владик 3пп    53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292   Владик 3пп     53.25932749912   83.6534465959292
3  Калининград    53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292  Калининград     53.25932749912   83.6534465959292
0  Москва, 1п.  53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  Москва; 1п.   53.2555095749943   83.6533059729708
1    Питер, 2п  53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708    Питер; 2п   53.2555095749943   83.6533059729708
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Но это пол дела, т.к. после перенесенных данных, на старом месте их нужно удалить. В столбце "Общие данные" должны остаться, только города.

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.extractall()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
data2[["Широта", "Долгота"]] = (
    data2["Общие данные"]
    .str.extractall(r"\b(\d+\.\d+),\s*(\d+\.\d+)\b").reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    .astype("float")
)
```

результат:

```
In [192]: data2
Out[192]:
           Имя                          Координаты                                     Общие данные     Широта    Долгота
0  Москва, 1п.  53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  Москва, 1п., 53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  53.255510  83.653306
1    Питер, 2п  53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708    Питер, 2п, 53.2555095749943, 83.6533059729708  53.255510  83.653306
2   Владик 3пп    53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292     Владик 3пп, 53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292  53.259327  83.653447
3  Калининград    53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292    Калининград, 53.25932749912, 83.6534465959292  53.259327  83.653447

In [193]: data2.dtypes
Out[193]:
Имя              object
Координаты       object
Общие данные     object
Широта          float64
Долгота         float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Но это пол дела, т.к. после перенесенных данных, на старом месте их нужно удалить. В столбце "Общие данные" должны остаться, только города.

Comment: @Nevskiy А вы сами не хотите что-нибудь сделать попробовать? Вам показали, как это в принципе делается, несколько вариантов. Вы меняете вопрос на ходу - так не принято. Ну и этих ответов достаточно, чтобы вы их приспособили под изменившиеся условия.

Comment: Извиняюсь, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Nevskiy Если так и не разберётесь - задайте новый вопрос отдельно. Но сначала попробуйте поразбираться в том коде, который вам дали, и в Pandas. Тут ничего сверхсложного, просто чётко определитесь что нужно получить и пробуйте менять код, пробуйте разные варианты. Фактически, мы тоже пробуем разные варианты, пока не получится нужный, просто мы знаем много вариантов из которых можно собрать этот "конструктор".

Answer (score 2):

Наверняка можно как-то более "векторно" это сделать, используя строковые функции самого `Pandas`, но навскидку можно так, работает:

```
def split_data(data, n):
    for line in data:
        yield float(line.split(',')[n].strip())

data2['Широта'] = list(split_data(data2['Общие данные'].values, -2))
data2['Долгота'] = list(split_data(data2['Общие данные'].values, -1))
```

Comment: Я отредактировал задание. Столбец имя, изменил на города.

Comment: Пишет ошибку:

    yield float(line.split(',')[n].strip())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1п.'

Comment: Я поменял код, пробуйте

Comment: Получилось, спасибо.